# Excel VBA - passing argument to property

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, Im trying to pass an argument value to property 'VerticalAlignment'. The error I get is: "Unable to set the HorizontalAlignment property of the Range class". Clearly the problem is with the 'horzAlign' & 'vertAlign' values, however, what?

```
' Merge the range & horizontal & vertical
' alignment as per arguments
Sub mergeCellsWithLeftAlign(ByVal curRange As Range, _
    ByVal horzAlign As String, ByVal vertAlign As String)

        With curRange
            .HorizontalAlignment = horzAlign
            .VerticalAlignment = vertAlign
            .MergeCells = True
        End With
End Sub
```

This is being called in another procedure like this:

```
Call mergeCellsWithLeftAlign(Range("F10:F11"), "xlLeft", "xlBottom")
```

Comment: what are possible values of your `horzAlign` and `vertAlign`

Comment: @psychicebola Paul has answered it. Its a integer constant. Thanks

Comment: @psychicebola: no matter: they should not be String for start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the VBA Help the values must not be `"xlLeft", "xlBottom"` but `xlLeft, xlBottom`, i.e. without the quotes - they are integer constants.

Answer (score 0):

RTFM.  From the help:

> The value of this property can be set to one of the following
>   constants:
>
> xlBottom  xlCenter  xlDistributed  xlJustify  xlTop

Answer (score 0):

according to msdn, the property values must be one of these:

horizontal:

- xlCenter
- xlDistributed
- xlJustify
- xlLeft
- xlRight

vertical:

- xlBottom
- xlCenter
- xlDistributed
- xlJustify
- xlTop